# ViewBinding class not generated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have enabled view binding in my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

and I've split my layout folders to maintain an order because it is a big project. However, my ViewBinding class isn't being generated.

[image: Picture of the error]

How to solve this error?

Comment: Can you pls post your .xml file here.

Comment: "I've split my layout folders to maintain an order because it is a big project" -- I am under the impression that view binding does not support this sort of Gradle-based resource shuffling.

Comment: Yess. ViewBinding doesn't work when you have split your XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, it is probably because you made subfolders in the layout folder which isn't something you are supposed to do

However, there are plugins like [this](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-file-grouping-plugin-v1-1-170361ce921d):

Which allow you to have virtual folders.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I had to update my android studio to a version 3.6 or greater. It will resolve the issue.

Comment: You are right, in order to use View binding you need AS and gradle plugin 3.6 or higher